# Real world use of Contravariance and Covariance in .net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke, covariance, contravariance

I Want to know the real world scenario where we use **Contravariance and Covariance** with program.I saw various blogs but I am still confused where I can implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever written a `foreach`? If you have then you have used *Covariance* so that is the real world usage. You can use `foreach` on any type which implements [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is the signature for `IEnumerable`:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
                             ^^
                             ||
                    // See the above out keyword
```

That `out` keyword is for *covariance* so it applies only to return types.

Have you ever used the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, then you have used *contravariance*. Here is the signature:

```
public interface IComparer<in T>
                           ^^
                           ||
                   // See the above in keyword
```

That `in` keyword is for *contravariance* so it applies only to parameter types of the members of the interface.

And if the `out` and `in` keywords are missing then it applies to both input parameter and return parameters. That is called `invariance`.